# i wrote a generic ordered array class , and there is null pointer error occurring with the insert method when comparing the elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, generics

```
public class GenericOrderedArray<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private T[] a;
private int n;

public GenericOrderedArray(Class<T> clazz, int max) {
    a = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, max);
    n = 0;
}

public void insert(T value) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    //this is where error goes ,the compare to method throws a null pointer exception
        if (a[j] != null && a[j].compareTo(value) > 0)
            break;
    for (int k = n; k < j; k--)
        a[k] = a[k - 1];
    a[j] = value;
    n++;
}

public boolean delete(T value) {
    boolean result = false;
    int hit = find(value);
    if (hit == -1)
        return result;
    else {
        for (int i = hit; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
        }
        n--;
    }
    return result;
}


    //binary search implements find method 
public int find(T value) {
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = n - 1;
    int curIn;
    while (true) {
        curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
        if (a[curIn].equals(value))
            return curIn;
        else if (lowerBound > upperBound) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (a[curIn].compareTo(value) < 0)
                lowerBound = curIn + 1;
            else {
                upperBound = curIn - 1;
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 100;
    GenericOrderedArray<Integer> ints = new GenericOrderedArray<>(Integer.class, max);
    ints.insert(2);
    ints.insert(4);
    ints.insert(1);
}
}
```

The array compares each elements and put the moving the smaller element to the lower index. This may be a dummy question. The exception occurs when comparing the elements, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you add the exception error message and stack trace.

Comment: Well, I just tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: Yes the example "works" without error. Lior Barnea provide a good hints to. I don't know if it will solve your problem. Maybe you should check that `value` is not null too.

Comment: you don't actually need `Array.newInstance` or the class of the components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int k = n; **k < j**; k--)
    a[k] = a[k - 1];
```

I think you should have **k > j**

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you insert your first element, you are comparing a[j] with the element to be inserted. But, since there is no element at a[0] the first time you insert a element a NPE will be thrown.

You should start your insert method by checking if the first element is NULL. If a[0]=NULL you simply insert the element there, else you continue with your compare statement

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Tried on Linux, jdk6 and jdk7.
In general, the only way the compare method may throw a NPE in your code is when you pass a null as the value, because you check a[j] for null. Make sure that you don't pass null to the insert method.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) interface documentation. It states:

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.(This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

Hence, if you try to compare anything with null, there should be a NPE.